# Directory alias vs variable in profile

Tags: alias, nix

What are the advantages of aliasing a directory (in my .profile) as opposed to setting a shell variable to it (and exporting of course).

```
alias MY_DIR=/usr/local/data/test/
```

vs

```
MY_DIR=/usr/local/data/test/
export MY_DIR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alias only works for commands.  That is, the shell will check argv[0] for aliases, it will check every part of argv for sigiled variables (like $MY_DIR).  A visual demonstration:

```
g3 0 /home/jj33 > alias FOO=bar
g3 0 /home/jj33 > FOO
-ksh: bar: not found
g3 127 /home/jj33 > echo FOO
FOO
g3 0 /home/jj33 > BAZ=bar
g3 0 /home/jj33 > $BAZ
-ksh: bar: not found
g3 127 /home/jj33 > echo $BAZ
bar
```